# How to get the actual data from the function hist

Tags: r

I am very new to R, so I apologize if this is a basic question.

Is there any way to have the data behind the graph the function "hist" produces?

I don't need the graphic, I just the data.

In general, it would be nice if I have the option to only get the data behind the functions that produce graphs and prevent drawing the actual plots.

Thank you,

Comment: look at `str(hist(x))` -- `hist(x)$counts` should give you what you want -- pretty sure this is a duplicate...otherwise see `table` and/or create your own summaries with packages such as `dplyr` or `data.table`

Comment: the `value` section of `?hist` and the `plot` argument are well documented

Comment: You probably just want to assign it: `x <- hist(...)` then `x` will have everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to obtain the original data behind the function `hist`.

If you are referring just to the data required to generate the plot, they are stored in `hist(x)$mids` and `hist(x)$count`, which contains respectively the midpoints and the counts. If you want just the data without drawing the plot, you can call this function on the object `hist`:

```
dataHist<-function(y){
  rbind(y$mids,y$counts)    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `hist(*yourvectorname*, plot = FALSE)`